# Number x and a list of coefficients and returns the result of the polynomial 1 + 2 + ⋯ +   applied to the first argument

Tags: recursion, racket

This is my function:

```
(: compute-poly : Number (Listof Number) -> Number)
(define (compute-poly x numlist)
  (: compute-poly-tail : Number (Listof Number) Number Number -> Number)
  (define (compute-poly-tail xn list n acc)
    (if (null? list) acc
    (compute-poly-tail (first list) (rest list) (+ acc (* (first list) (expt xn n))) (+ n 1))))
  (compute-poly-tail x numlist 0 0))
```

I get the below error:

```
. Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Integer
  given: Number in: n
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This program

```
#lang typed/racket

(: compute-poly : Number (Listof Number) -> Number)
(define (compute-poly x numlist)
  (: compute-poly-tail : Number (Listof Number) Number Number -> Number)
  (define (compute-poly-tail xn list n acc)
    (if (null? list) acc
    (compute-poly-tail (first list) (rest list) (+ acc (* (first list) (expt xn n))) (+ n 1))))
  (compute-poly-tail x numlist 0 0))
```

runs without any errors on version 6.7.

Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in line 6 where you have:

```
(compute-poly-tail (first list) ... (+ acc (* (first list) (expt xn n))) (+ n 1))))
```

First, you have replaced `xn` with `(first list)` in your recursive call. Since `x` is used in each term being added, what you should have is `(compute-poly-tail xn ...)` for every recursive call.

Second, the order of the last two arguments for this function is `(compute-poly-tail ... n acc)`, so in your recursive call, you should rearrange the last two arguments to correspond with the definition argument order.

So line 6 should become:

```
(compute-poly-tail xn ... (+ n 1) (+ acc (* (first list) (expt xn n))))))
```

Here is a sample revision:

```
(: compute-poly (-> Number (Listof Number) Number Number))
(define (compute-poly x lst n)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ (* (car lst) (expt x n))
         (compute-poly x (cdr lst) (add1 n)))))
```

and then,

```
> (compute-poly 1 '(1 2 3 4 5) 0)
- : Number
15
```